# Is the Dynomak concept physically sound?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I recently stumpled upon this article:

- [Inside the Dynomak: A Fusion Technology Cheaper Than Coal](https://spectrum.ieee.org/energy/nuclear/inside-the-dynomak-a-fusion-technology-cheaper-than-coal/)

Is the Dynomak concept physically sound? What kind of challenges could it run into? Can it make fusion energy really cheaper than coal?

Comment: the idea of using current injected into the plasma to create part of the confinement field is not new. For an excellent review of the history and physics of fusion power, see Seife's book.

Comment: AFAIk the Dynomak researchers have not had a fusion reaction at all yet.  They're working on confinement problems and it's early stage.  Be wary of hype like this as it's primarily aimed at getting research funding.  They can't know what a real production reactor would cost until they actually have a design to try that with.  I've been hearing hype like this for decades, and so will you, in all probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0920379614002518), my executive summary would be that this design is even more unproven than tokamaks. Indeed, tokamaks have at least demonstrated that they can confine plasma enough to achieve fusion, the issue being whether a tokamak can produce more energy than it consumes. On the contrary, at the time that article was written, they only have a possible mechanism, imposed-dynamo current drive (IDCD), that they plan to use to control the currents in the plasma. But this had to be shown to work. This is crucial, note, because in such a spheromak, the confining magnetic field is generated by the currents in the plasma. Moreover, this is only the first step, as the article points out too: the fluctuations of the magnetic field induced by IDCD might eventually spoil the confinement of the plasma. That such fluctuations have that effect would be the traditional view actually but the article argues otherwise. Anyway, as the article acknowledged, this was still unproven as well. Thus pretty much the entire concept is experimentally unproven: right now, we are talking about simulations only.

A note about cheaper than coal although this has nothing to do with physics: pretty much every source of energy is cheaper than coal these days! A pretty pointless quote for an otherwise reasonably good article…

Comment: At the time of the article's writing (2014), coal was still cheaper than solar and natural gas. https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=25392

Comment: @chris An article about a technology which will, optimistically, come to fruition in 20 years, I would expect it not to just look at the situation at the date of publication. Especially when the trend was so obvious.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. To be fair to the authors, though, natural gas prices were rising in 2013 and 2014, so the trend may not have been as obvious as it seems in retrospect ;)